# Importing tests from another project using Gradle

Tags: gradle, jar

I have a microservice that has a sub-folder full of integration tests written in Groovy.  These tests basically make a bunch of REST calls.  Gradle is configured to produce a JAR for these tests like so:

```
//Explicitly add the integration tests to the JAR
jar {
  from sourceSets.test.output
}
```

Unzipping the JAR shows the Groovy tests that were in the project.  That seems good so far.

Now, there is a larger project that I want to use (in a different git repo) that will import these tests and run them.  The plan is to import several other test suites in a similar fashion and build a sort of uber-test project.  This project can import the test JAR as a dependency as testCompile.  I can see the JAR in the SourceSets using IDEA's gradle plugin.  However, I can't get the tests to run using `gradle test`.

How can I modify the uber-test project to execute these imported test?

Comment: When executing `test` tasks, Gradle will search unit tests to be executed in `src/test/java` ; it will not scan the dependencies (even if defined in `testCompile` scope) to find extra test classes.  what you could do is to create some test suite classes in your test source folder,using Junit Suite runner (`@RunWith(Suite.class)`), and "import" the test classes from there using `@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestClassInJar1.class, TestClassInJar2.class})`

Comment: you might have errors running the tests packaged in the jar, for example if tests classes are written to load some resources from /src/test/resources using `Class.getResource(..)`

Comment: I removed the _spock_ tag from this question because it is completely unrelated to Spock.